# Paypal: How do I create a Donate Now button with variable amounts

Tags: paypal

I want to create a Donate Now button that has variable amounts similar to what Paypal uses on its Giving site.

How is this accomplished? I tried using the button builders to no avail. I'd really like to be able to implement this client side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[PayPal's giving website](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/search-cause) uses Express Checkout solution to allow user enter the amount to be charged on the client website.

It's just that the button to initiate is pictured as "Donation button".

For more information on Express Checkout implementation: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/